# Bind a repeater dynamically inside another repeater?

Tags: c#, data-binding, repeater

I have this code:

```
<asp:Repeater id="repeaterCategories" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="categorie-item">
            ...

            <asp:Repeater id="repeaterSubCategories" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    ...
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>                    
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and `repeaterSubCategories` must be `repeaterCategories.SubCategories`, for each `repeaterCategories`. So I have to bind dynamically (for each first repeater iteration) a list of sub categories.

Can I do it? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a nested repeater like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server"></asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You can use this to bind to it:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var data = ((MyClass)e.Item.DataItem).Subcategories;
    var repeater2 = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2");
    repeater2.DataSource = data;
    repeater2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: uhm, but how can I bind `Repeater1.SubCategories` for each `Repeater2`?

Comment: Edited my answer to include how to cast `DataItem` for `e` to your class and subcategories.

Comment: (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2"); important vs ((Repeater)Repeater1.FindControl("Repeater2") .  :)  Thank you for this.

Comment: This is awesome but what if the parent repeater's DataTable for example is needed in the sub repeater's data? Would you recommend to make the DataTable global which can be used in the ItemDataBound?